# Converting Drupal Content Types

Tags: 7, nodes, migrations, views

What are the steps needed and modules required to convert a large number of nodes from one content type to another, both in Drupal 7. They are fairly simple. If you know of a good tutorial that would be great too.

All my searching seems to bring up migrate which I thought was from 6 to 7.

I've tried node convert but I'm not sure how to use actions or if it can do many nodes at once.

And would it be possible for the URL alias and the taxonomy selections to be transfered?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Node Convert](https://drupal.org/project/node_convert) module.

> Node Convert adds a menu tab "Convert" on the node view page, i.e. node/1/convert, which gives the ability of converting the node from its current node type to another node type. Also it gives the ability of transfering all the custom CCK field values of the current node type to the destination CCK fields, or discard them. As of 5.x-1.4 you can bulk convert many nodes of the same type, to another one that can be accesed in Administer → Content → Convert Nodes.
>
> The module has been tested on converting node types with the following CCK fields:
>
> - Text
> - Number
> - Image
> - Node reference
> - User reference
> - Link
> - Date
> - Datestamp
> - Email
> - Audio
> - Video

Here is the documentation for the module: https://drupal.org/node/291564

Answer (score 1):

Two different ways to use node convert for converting a lot of nodes:

1. [Use the node convert API](https://www.drupal.org/node/2307851), this requires writing some PHP, just like with [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate), but it's probably a lot simpler to wrap your head around.
2. [Use node conversion templates with Views Bulk Operations](http://blog.hsl.virginia.edu/drupalpress/node-convert-and-views-bulk-operations/), see also [d.o: Create node conversion templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2307829).